# Attach a PDF file to email - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, email, attachment

I want to send email with a PDF attachment.
I created PDF file, then I did the following which is wrong I believe:

```
// locate folder containing pdf file            
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String

let pdfFileName = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("chart.pdf")
let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pdfFileName)
mc.addAttachmentData(fileData, mimeType: "pdf", fileName: chart)
```

Before sending the email, I can see attached `chart.pdf`, but when I sent the email, it was sent without attachment and this is because I didn't attached correctly the file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are passing wrong `mimeType` to `addAttachmentData()`. Use `application/pdf` instead of `pdf`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i change to : mc.addAttachmentData(fileData, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: pdfFileName), but still email is sent without attachment.

Comment: Are you sure that `fileData` is not nil? and pdf is actually present on that path?

Comment: you are right, fileData was nil, then i had to change the "documentsPath" in let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: documentsPath) to "pdfFileName". now it is working very well. thank you very much

Comment: Glad to help you out :)

Answer (score 5):

we can attache PDF file with email and send it programmatically

with **Swift 2.2**

```
@IBAction func sendEmail(sender: UIButton)
    {
        //Check to see the device can send email.
        if( MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() )
        {
            print("Can send email.")

            let mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self

            //Set to recipients
            mailComposer.setToRecipients(["your email address heres"])

            //Set the subject
            mailComposer.setSubject("email with document pdf")

            //set mail body
            mailComposer.setMessageBody("This is what they sound like.", isHTML: true)

            if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("All_about_tax", ofType: "pdf")
            {
                print("File path loaded.")

                if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath)
                {
                    print("File data loaded.")
                    mailComposer.addAttachmentData(fileData, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: "All_about_tax.pdf")

                }
            }

            //this will compose and present mail to user
            self.presentViewController(mailComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            print("email is not supported")
        }
    }

    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?)
    {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: I have an error: Use of undeclared type  `MFMailComposeViewController` and `MFMailComposeResult`

Answer (score 3):

First one, import:

```
import MessageUI
```

And implement de Email Delegate, like

```
public class MyViewController : UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate { ...
```

If you have the file or the `Data` type, you can use this function:

```
let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("chart", ofType: "pdf")
let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath)
sendEmail(data:fileData)
```

**Swift 4**

```
func sendEmail(data:Data?){
    if( MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() ) {
        let mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self

        mailComposer.setToRecipients(["john@stackoverflow.com", "mrmins@mydomain.com", "anotheremail@email.com"])
        mailComposer.setSubject("Cotización")
        mailComposer.setMessageBody("My body message", isHTML: true)

        if let fileData = data {
            mailComposer.addAttachmentData(fileData, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: "MyFileName.pdf")
       }


       self.present(mailComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
    }
    print("Email is not configured")

}
```

And the `compose`:

```
public func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?){
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("sent!")
    }
```